# My SO question: Delete? Accept, but explain what I did instead? Start a new topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer

Apologies if Meta is not the place for this. Let me know if not, and I will delete. (If it's an OK Meta question, I'd take suggestions on a better title!)

I asked a rather badly-worded-novel-of an excel/vba question (after a long search). Heading was fine, text was questionable:

[Combine two overlapping tables of date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896004/combine-two-overlapping-tables-of-date-ranges)

I received an answer that DOES work with the data given, but is too slow for my purposes (because that data was just a tiny bit of a larger project) and is tightly tied to example data. I finally figured it out on my own.

I would self-answer, but my code is 200 lines and wouldn't make sense without the spreadsheet. (Plus, my VBA coding is definitely not "best practice" stuff - it's a side-language.)

But I can *explain* what I did.

I've searched for an answer to this particular problem several times over the last few years, so I am pretty sure that the question itself is a good question.

I HATE coming to SO and finding a question very close to my issue, but without an answer, or with a very specific coding answer that can't easily be revamped for what I'm doing.

Should I:

1. Delete the question and know that I now know what I need to know? I'd hate for someone to find this and think, "Wow, that was exactly my question, but unfortunately, the answer is too slow/very specific to the data"
2. Mark the answer as correct, even though I didn't use it (it DOES work, and is simpler than my solution, though slower and data specific) and leave it?
3. Explain what I did briefly, without code and mark one of the two (mine or the original answer-er) as correct?
4. Delete the question and create a self-answer question with a limited data set, not the novel I wrote for this question, and again, explain how I solved it without having to post 200 lines of code and a spreadsheet?

I think it's a valuable question, given how many times I have searched for it. I think an explanation of the logic would have enabled me to figure things out a lot sooner.

What is considered the best/the most useful thing to do?

Comment: *Plus, my VBA coding is definitely not "best practice" stuff* It doesn't have to be *perfect* to be useful.

Comment: I get that, but everything I do is pretty rushed, and sometimes I'm bandaiding around myself. I think I'm going to try to write an explanation, though, so hopefully that will suffice.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "novel"

Comment: @kojow7 "Novel" here means [a long work of fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novel)

Comment: @kojow7 In English describing something as a "novel" is a figure of speech used to describe a document or a what some one has said as unnecessarily long and/or having too many words.  The reason Novel is used as such is as ConCave described (literal definition refers to a type of long form text).  Similar phrases include  "long winded", "essay", and "dissertation".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While I can't speak to the VB portion of your specific question, I will say the *least* constructive things to do would be to delete anything.  Your question is fine and doesn't have any downvotes on it, so removing it would be a pity (and likely hurt you in the future since you *do* have an answer on it).

<sup>You also physically can't because [there's a positively-scored answer on your question that isn't yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/175248).</sup>

From there, what to do next depends on what your goal is.

- If you want to share the knowledge of what you've done and how you solved your problem, **feel encouraged to answer it.**
- If you want to thank the user for answering your question, and you're reasonably certain that it *helped*, then accept their answer.

You're not obligated to do either of these things, but I personally believe that answering your own question with a concise explanation would be the best option here.

Comment: Thanks! That positive vote is my vote, btw. I'm not really concerned about my SO "Rep", just more concerned that someone gets an answer to the same question, if that makes sense. I guess I'll make an attempt at a concise explanation. As for accepting...the answer WORKED, but I didn't use any part of it, so I'll have to think about that one.

Comment: @Julie "accept" means only one thing - "answer was helpful to OP" - so if it was helpful (and preferably correct, also correctness mostly indicated by votes) there is no problem to accept it even if you ended up not using the answer (presumably because you've gained some knowledge from the answer). If you going to provide your own answer you'd need to think which one you find more useful - perfectly fine to accept your own in such case.